# Getting NameError for an exception handling

Tags: django, django-models, error-handling

I wanted to list an object(club) detail on a page by extracting its id from url and giving it to django models api. It is working when that id exist in the database. But when I try giving id in url which does not exist then the model api gives this error:

> > > club = Club.objects.get(id=8)
> > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >             File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 131, in get
> > >           return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 366, in get
> > >           % self.model._meta.object_name)
> > >       DoesNotExist: Club matching query does not exist.

So I added an exception handler for this error in my view. Here is the code:

```
def club_detail(request, offset):
    try:
        club_id = int(offset)
        club = Club.objects.get(id=club_id)
    except (ValueError, DoesNotExist):
        raise HTTP404()
    return render_to_response('home/club_detail.html', {'club': club }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

But it is not catching DoesNotExist error and instead giving a NameError in browser:

```
NameError at /club/8/
  global name 'DoesNotExist' is not defined
  Request Method:   GET
  Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/club/8/
  Django Version:   1.4.1
  Exception Type:   NameError
  Exception Value:  
  global name 'DoesNotExist' is not defined
```

How can I make it working? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DoesNotExist` is implemented as an attribute of the model itself. Change your line to:

```
    except (ValueError, Club.DoesNotExist):
```

Alternatively, since all `DoesNotExist` errors inherit the `ObjectDoesNotExist` class, you can do:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

...

    except (ValueError, ObjectDoesNotExist):
```

as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-do-not-return-querysets).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use DoesNotExist directly - it shoul'd be Club.DoesNotExist so your code would look like:

```
def club_detail(request, offset):
    try:
        club_id = int(offset)
        club = Club.objects.get(id=club_id)
    except (ValueError, Club.DoesNotExist):
        raise HTTP404()
    return render_to_response('home/club_detail.html', {'club': club }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `DoesNotExist`:

```
from django.core.exceptions import DoesNotExist
```

Comment: I tried this but it is giving ImportError. And I also opened exceptions.py file, but there is no DoesNotExist class. (I'm running django 1.4)

Comment: `cannot import name DoesNotExist`